# Can a Research Paper on Classical Mechanics make it to a good journal?

Tags: classical-mechanics, research-level

I am starting University in September, 2014. I have some knowledge already on classical mechanics as I took optional Applied Math courses (called Mechanics 1 and Mechanics 2) in my mathematics A-Level. I am also self-studying the book Classical Mechanics by Goldstein, Poole and Safko to gain a deeper understanding of the subject.

Pretty much all of the universities I am applying spend freshman year teaching Calculus, Classical Mechanics, Introuctory Chemistry, Thermodynamics and Introductory Biology. There are courses on Modern Physics, Introductory Quantum Mechanics and Special Relativity in the second semester but most of the real stuff starts in the second year if you select something like Physics or (Applied or otherwise) Mathematics as a major.

Now, the thing is, I like doing experiments and formulating equations. I was just wondering if I could, perhaps, write a research paper that formulates some simple effective theory, or perhaps deals with the applications of previous classical mechanical theories in new conditions, or details new experimental ways to test those theories (excuse my vagueness, university is about nine months away and I've only started learning about this stuff) and have that research paper printed in a half-decent journal. Even if it isn't printed in a journal and I have to publish it myself via my university or otherwise, will it be important enough to be mentioned in the applications for MS and PhD. programmes of high-ranked universities like Cambridge, MIT and ETH Zurich after I complete my BS?

Comment: You could always post it to arXiv under math-ph if it's mathematical enough, or their classical physics section...

Comment: @AlexNelson I see. Thanks. Will that be authentic enough to be mentioned in MS or PhD. applications?

Comment: I would think that yes, arXiv papers are okay for putting on an application.

Comment: Yeah, eprints are fine for grad school applications.

Comment: Look for instance at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0181). Not only was it published in Phys.Rev.Lett., but also made quite a splash. (It was also in the journal club on this site).

Comment: You can also ask on [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com).